# Take a photo every 5 seconds

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel

I am developing a panel, which from time to time runs a process and generates an image within it. Once the image is generated, you need to take a photo to save it for the changes that are made.

I already developed the part where the images change, but when I take the photos, they all come out blank. Add a delay on the screen thinking that it should take a while to take the photo of the panel later, but it still comes out blank and if there is something inside the panel, since I am resizing it according to the size of what is updated.

Can you help me to see where my error is? Or guide me to obtain an optimal result?, I also tried using a timer, but it gives me the same result, any ideas?

This is the code developed.

```
sub buldimages()
     Panel1.Refresh()
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    
     segondGa(varName)
                'Timer1.Start()
End Sub

    Function segondGa(nameLine As String)
        Dim widthOldPuno = Panel1.Width
        Dim heightOldPuno = Panel1.Height
        Dim widthOldPdos = Panel2.Width
        Dim heightOldPdos = Panel2.Height
        Dim coordenada, i As Integer

        For Each obj As Control In Panel1.Controls
            coordenada = obj.Location.X
        Next

        Panel1.Width = widthOldPuno + (coordenada - Panel1.Width)
        Panel2.Width = Panel1.Width + 113
        Panel2.Height = heightOldPdos - 65

        Dim nameLineB As String = nameLine

        Using bmp = New Bitmap(Panel2.Width, Panel2.Height)
            Panel2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))

            Dim bmp2 As New Bitmap(bmp.Width * 3, bmp.Height * 3)
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2)
            gr.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height))

            bmp2.Save("C:\TEMP\" & nameLineB & ".png")
        End Using

        Panel2.Width = widthOldPdos
        Panel2.Height = heightOldPdos
        Panel1.Width = widthOldPuno

    End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim seconds As Integer
    Label1.Text = seconds + 1
    If Label1.Text = "5" Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do here. + What's the use of: `For Each obj As Control In Panel1.Controls coordenada = obj.Location.X Next`? To then: `Panel1.Width = widthOldPuno + (coordenada - Panel1.Width)`? `Dim nameLine As String = nameLine` (never used)? -- The Timer is doing nothing at all and the Label will always show `1`. Try to explain, at least, what *take the photos* means and implies.

Comment: I'd love to see some screenshots of what you are "generating", and how Panel1 and Panel2 are somehow involved...

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for your answer.`coordenada` is to get the last position in X of the object in Panel1, this is necessary to resize the Panel1 because Panel1 have more objects inside and need all pictures of this objects. Sorry `nameLine` its a mistake, I updated the code. The timer I dont know why doesnt increase. Taking the photo of that panel is because it is necessary to take the .PNG files to be able to insert them later in a file as evidence

Comment: @Idle_Mind, Inside Panel2, there is Panel1 and a Picturebox that has a still image, this is because you need to take the whole picture. When taking the photo of Panel2, you should see the Picturebox and the content of Panel1, but only the PcitureBox is seen and Panel1 is blank, even though there are objects inside it, and I know that because if the coordinates are being taken to resize the Panels objects.
Sorry I can't show you a picture, you know, customer.

Comment: @Jimi, exchange the Timer1 for `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)`